# How to get normal images from Facebook Graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Currently I am using Facebook Graph api to get feeds from Facebook, but past 1 month onwards I am getting smaller images instead of normal images and used **_n,_l and _b** in my URL but all these are not working.

Comment: did you already try something by yourself?

Comment: yes i works a lot and still i am working on same thing and worked a lot from the past 4 days but unable to found correct solution will u please help me Ethaan

Comment: Hi mohan what its the exactly error are you getting?

Comment: try to get like this and tell me if works. `http://graph.facebook.com/[user_id]/picture?type=square` use the square option

Comment: Did you try with the square option?

Comment: Hi Mr.Ethaan,i am not getting any error because all things are fine and only problem is the images in the facebook feeds are to small compared with real ones.How to get large images in the feeds Mr.  Ethaan and thanks for your response. iam using this url to get feed https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?access_token={access_token}&limit=200 is their any changes needed in the facebook api url which i am using

Comment: Mr. Ethaan **type=square** is not working,https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?access_token={access_token}&limit=200 is there any changes in the facebook graph api url

Comment: hmm it should work did you have the project on github?

Comment: Mr.Ethaan final i got it and i have one more problem i.e i am getting only limitted number of feeds only 25 feeds is their any option to get more feeds and  i mentioned limit=200 in my URL but i am getting only 25